# Why my results of sort algorithm based on OpenCL are wrong?

Tags: c, sorting, opencl

I wrote an odd and even sorting algorithm based on OpenCL and C, and also a serial odd and even sorting algorithm. But when I tried to run them (e.g. I randomly generated an array with 2,000 elements) and then compared them with the 224th element, I found that they were different. But on a small sample, they are all the same. Why is that?

because of some reason, I need to hide my OpenCL code. sorry

Here is my OpenCL code.

```
__kernel void 
odd_sort(__global int *array,
              int len,
              int array_size) 
{

}

__kernel void 
even_sort(__global int *array,
              int len,
              int array_size) 
{
    
}
```

Here is the serial program.

```
void serial()
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    bool sorted = false;
    while(!sorted)
    {
        sorted = true;

        // odd sort
        for (i = 1; i < array_size - 1; i+=2)
            if (array[i] > array[i+1])
            {
                tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = tmp;
                sorted = false;

            }
            
        // even sort
        for (j = 0; j < array_size - 1; j+=2)
            if (array[j] > array[j+1])
            {
                tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = tmp;
                sorted = false;
            }
    }
    // print(array, array_size);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

barrier is only a synchronization point for all threads within a (local) work group. But you want to have a global synchronization for all threads. You can't do such a global synchronization in a kernel; you would have to split the kernel into two parts and repeatedly call the odd and even kernels. Finishung a kernel represents a global synchronization point.

In your case it works on small scale, i.e. if you have only a single work group, because then the local size is equal to global size and the barrier works on all available threads.

Comment: Could i write two kernel functions in only one opencl file?  Just like the edited opencl code above. Cause I am new to opencl, If so, could you please give me some examples. So that I can learn from them. Thx

Comment: Yes you can do that.